Issue with `publisher` in `inbook` in `chem-acs` in `biblatex`
I need to generate bibliography entries for book chapters that look like this:

Frenkel, D.; Smit, B. Chapter 4 - Molecular Dynamics Simulations. In
Under- standing Molecular Simulation, Second Edition; Academic Press,
2002; pp 63–107.

using chem-acs in biblatex. My bibfile looks like this:
@inbook{frenkel&smit2002chapter4,
  title = {Chapter 4 - Molecular Dynamics Simulations},
  editor = {Frenkel, Daan and Smit, Berend},
  booktitle = {Understanding Molecular Simulation},
  publisher = {Academic Press},
  edition = {Second Edition},
  address = {San Diego, CA},
  pages = {63--107},
  year = {2002},
  isbn = {978-0-12-267351-1},
  doi = {10.1016/B978-012267351-1/50006-7},
  url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780122673511500067},
  author = {Frenkel, Daan and Smit, Berend}
}

and my code looks like this:
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext{In}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext{\emph{\thefield{booktitle}}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{\thefield{edition}}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printtext{\thefield{publisher}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{\thefield{year}}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printtext{pp \thefield{pages}.}%
}

Using this code, my entry is printing without the publisher field as:

Frenkel, D.; Smit, B. Chapter 4 - Molecular Dynamics Simulations. In
Under- standing Molecular Simulation, Second Edition; 2002; pp 63–107.

I have no idea why publisher is being treated differently from edition or year or how to fix that. I am using pdfLaTeX on Overleaf. How can I add "Academic Press, " right before "2002"?

It is hard to try things from just snippets. But my crystal ball says you want \thelist{publisher}.

@gusbrs, I was unsure what all I needed to provide without being extra. What you suggested was exactly what I needed, though! Thanks!!!

Felipe, you should always strive to provide a MWE. It makes your question stand a much better chance to get answers, because it trims down guesswork on what your context might be like, and it makes those who might be able to answer have a concrete document to manipulate.

Can I ask why the built-in formatting isn't working for you here? Have you for example been asked to change something by the ACS? (I'm wondering if I need to tweak the style.)

Using \printtext{\thefield{...}} and friends to print field contents is extremely unidiomatic. Use \printfield instead. That way you can use \DeclareFieldFormat for the field formatting and don't need to add in \emph and friends directly.

@JosephWright I've had to manipulate the chem-acs style to generate references in the format required by my graduate school for PhD theses.

As per @gusbrs suggestion, all I needed was to use \thelist for publisher.
